# Where can I find my squadmates on the Normandy?

Tags: mass-effect-3

From what I remember of previous games, each squadmate I recruit will set up in a different part of the Normandy.  It's usually important to talk with them all between missions, but I find myself running to and fro trying to find each new member's quarters on the ship.

Is there a map or a listing of each of the squadmates/major crewmembers and where I can find them on the ship?  Something organized by deck would be ideal.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: @murgatroid99, I play on the Xbox 360, but probably a platform-agnostic answer would work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This list is complete only up to the point I'm at in the game. I believe I am missing Tali and Kaidan (since I've got Ashley in my game).

Full squad members are bold.

### CIC Level

> - **EDI**: Bridge
> - Joker: Bridge
> - Traynor: By the galaxy map

### Crew Deck

> - **Liara** - Liara's Cabin (Miranda's old office)
> - **Garrus** - Main Battery
> - **Ashley** - Starboard Observation
> - Dr. Chakwas / Dr. Michel - Medical Lab

### Engineering

> - **Javik** - Port Cargo
> - Diana Allers - Starboard Cargo
> - Engineer Adams - Engineering

### Shuttle Bay

> - **Vega** - Forward-left of the elevator, by the workout equipment.
> - Cortez - Usually by either the shuttle or the terminal to the right of the elevator

Comment: To add to this Kaidan will end up in the same spot as Ashley and Tali sets up in engineering. On some occasions squad members might be somewhere else usually interacting with another squad member i.e. Garrus and James chatting on the crew deck.

Answer (score 1):

On the Xbox 360 version, you can click either analog stick to bring up a map of the current location (such as the Normandy or the Citadel). This has a list of every important character at each location in the area. This can also be accessed by going to "Map" in the pause menu.